# PDO not fetching row result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I took my old mysql script and attempted to convert it to a more secure PDO format. In my old script I ran a **SELECT field FROM table** statement then put it into a variable 
$Product = $row['product']; and run an IF and ELSE statement. If the users product = sony I wanted to echo " you may be interested in these  as well" Here is my example code below

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("host","username","password");
mysql_select_db("dbname");

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$q = "SELECT product FROM users WHERE username = ('$username')";

$r       = mysql_query($q);
$row     = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
$Product = $row['product'];

if($Product == "sony")
{
  echo "You may be interested in these as well"; 
}
?>
```

Now with the PDO-Statement, it seems you can not run the same sort of statement as before as easiliy. I tried assigning a variable to the row product that my query is selecting from but I get the error:

> Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array

Here is my code

```
<?php
session_start();

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password');

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$getProduct = $db->query("SELECT product FROM users  WHERE username = '$username'");
$getProduct->execute();

$Product = $getProduct['product'];

if($Product == "sony")
{
  echo "You may be interested in these as well"; 
}

?>
```

How can I pass the field "product" from the table I am selecting from to a variable with PDO and **IF the product ="sony" echo "message";**  ?

I also tried replacing the statements with this too with no success.

```
<?php
$query = $db->query("SELECT product FROM users  WHERE username = '$username'");
$query->execute();

$Product = $query ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$Product = $getProduct['product'];

if($Product == "sony")
{
    echo "You may be interested in these as well"; 
}

?>
```

The manual is not very friendly in regards to converting old statements to newer and secure ones, so I appreciate any direction on this, thank you.

Comment: It's no wonder the third bit doesn't work.  `$getproduct` doesn't exist there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to get 1 row and

```
$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to get all rows

You are expecting one row so use the first one.

Comment: Thank you! I used the first one like you said and worked like a charm! Also I made sure to define $getProduct. Again, thank you!